# Why do I get "Truncated incorrect date value" when using str_to_date()?

Tags: mysql

I have data in one of my tables as "Sun Dec 14 22:49:13 2014 -0800" and need to load it into another table but skipping the time filed i.e. HH:MM:SS.

I used:

```
insert into final_data
select Book_Name, Author_Name, Author_email,
str_to_date(substring_index(date_string,' ',4),'%a %b %d %Y'),
Total_Sold
from data;
```

> ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect date value: 'Sun Dec 14 22:49:13'

I can use `str_to_date(substring_index(date_string,' ',5),'%a %b %d %T %Y')` but that will add HH:MM:SS in the column as well.
Is there a way to load the data skipping HH:MM:SS ?
i.e instead of 2014-12-14 22:49:13 it diplays 2014-12-14

Comment: What is the type of the column in the old and the new table?

Comment: Both of them are varchar

Comment: Then why are you converting your output to date?

Comment: Please share table create statement and perhaps using the date format function during the select statement would work

Comment: create table final_data
    (Commit varchar(100),
    Author_Name varchar(100),
    Author_email varchar(100),
    Date_String varchar(50),
    Total_Sold int(4));

Comment: @mustaccio - data needs to be changed to YYY:MM:DD format for that field, which is originally a varchar type, without editing the existing table hence loading and formatting the data inot a new table.

Comment: You should edit the question to add the requested information; don't leave it in comments. To my point, if the target is `varchar` why bother using `str_to_date()` to convert the value to the date type, if it will be immediately converted back to string upon insert?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to pass your datetime column into date() function like this :

```
create table test (
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  datetime_string datetime,
  date_date date,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into test(datetime_string) values('2014-12-14 22:49:13');
update test set date_date = date(datetime_string);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc200b/1

Comment: it's more straightforward than your risky manipulation

Comment: It worked - thank you @eytienne and thanks a lot everyone for your help.

Comment: How is that even relevant??  The incoming data is not formatted correctly: "Sun Dec 14 22:49:13 2014 -0800"

Comment: could you up vote ? (because the formatting seems good in the error message so it worked)